# With Hibernate, can I mix table-per-subclass and a <map> within the same table?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm attempting to map an object model for "Promotions"; i.e., a customer enters a promo code during signup.

Different promo codes might have different types of "benefits", meaning what we are giving to the customer. 
For example: promo code XYZ123 will give the customer free minutes in his or her account, while a different promo code will offer various discounts off of the various subscription plans that the user can choose from when signing up.

In my domain model, I've modeled the different types of benefits as subclasses with an abstract superclass which has the common properties. I've chosen to model the different types as subclasses since some types of benefits will need different properties.

```
public abstract class Benefit {
    //getters/setters for common attributes
}

public class FreeMinutesBenefit extends Benefit {
    public int getFreeMinutes() {...}
    public void setFreeMinutes(int minutes} {...}
}

public class PriceDiscountBenefit extends Benefit {
    public Map<Plan, BigDecimal> getDiscountMap() {...}
    public void setDiscountMap(Map<Plan, BigDecimal> map) {...}
}
```

Rough SQL schema:

```
-- Parent table, maps promotion to benefits
create table Promo_Benefit (
    map_id integer auto-generated PRIMARY KEY,
    promo_id integer references PROMOTION(promo_id),
    type_id integer references BENEFIT_TYPES(type_id)
);

create table BenefitDetails_FreeMinutes (
    map_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    minutes integer not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (map_id) references Promo_Benefit(map_id)
);

create table BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount (
    map_id integer references Promo_Benefit(map_id),
    plan_id integer references Plans(plan_id),
    reduced_price numeric not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (map_id, plan_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (map_id) references Promo_Benefit(map_id)
);
```

I'm able to successfully map the basic properties of each subclass in my Hibernate mapping files, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to map the association 
between the PriceDiscountBenefit subclass and the Plan class.

I imagine this is because the primary key of the subclass table (BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount) isn't simply the `map_id` column - in other words, multiple rows in this subclass table will form a single PriceDiscountBenefit entity. From what I can see, it seems as if table-per-subclass support in Hibernate is meant for instances where a single row in the subclass table maps to a single row in the parent table - and mapping a `<map>` should refer to a second table which contains the keys/values.

Am I mapping this completely wrong? I can't tell if I'm having trouble because I'm butchering the table-per-subclass pattern.

Comment: Judging from the `Promo_Benefit` table, you have a Promotion class that has a one-to-many relationship to Benefit. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table-per-subclass strategy means you will have a table for each class in your hierarchy (including abstract classes, if any) and they will all have shared primary key. In your case that means you would have a separate table for each of `Benefit`, `FreeMinutesBenefit` and `PriceDiscountBenefit` classes. Your table names are a bit confusing and table structure is somewhat inconsistent with table-per-subclass.

Assuming that `map_id` is the shared primary key, `BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount` table must define it as such. `plan_id` belongs to a different ('mapping`) table that will hold a map between`PriceDiscountBenefit`,`Plan` and the decimal value. In other words:

```
create table BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount (
        map_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
        ... /* any other attributes, perhaps? */
        FOREIGN KEY (map_id) references Promo_Benefit(map_id)
);

create table BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount_Map (
        map_id integer references Promo_Benefit(map_id),
        plan_id integer references Plans(plan_id),
        reduced_price numeric not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (map_id, plan_id)
        FOREIGN KEY (map_id) references Promo_Benefit(map_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it feels really odd - because my BenefitDetails_PriceDiscount only has a single column (I have no need for other properties in this table), the FK. Seems ... dirty, from a database design perspective, as if I'm doing it only to support Hibernate

Comment: It's definitely somewhat odd from the database point of view, but that's the only way to do it. If you did not have a hierarchy at all (just a single entity with id and a map) you'd still have two separate tables - first with PK only and second for the map. If you're sure you'll never have any additional properties on PriceDiscountBenefit, you can try using table-per-hierarchy but then you'll end up with some NULL columns depending on entity.